# Highcharts How to center + and - inside map navigation buttons when styleMode: true

Tags: highcharts

I'm having a hard time to center the icons of the map navigation zoom buttons when I turn on styleMode and use the a generic theme supported by highcharts.
Can anyone detect the css styling that is connected to these buttons?

Custom styling styleMode: true

[Map button styleMode true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lduGk.png)

Generic styling styleMode: off

(the color is not right but they are centered and I cannot find the missing css style)

[Map button styleMode false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xHqH.png)

I tried to comment every part of the custom css code hoping to detect the right part but with no luck.

Comment: Can you add your code in JSfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This is unexpected behavior, so I reported a bug that you can track here:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18245

You can position text in the buttons using translate() CSS function:

```
.highcharts-button.highcharts-zoom-in text {
     transform: translateX(2px);
}
.highcharts-button.highcharts-zoom-out text {
     transform: translateX(3.5px);
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lvoc7hdm/